# XTS-File doesnt work for quantstrat

Tags: r, csv, xts, quantmod, quantstrat

I have created an `xts` file out of a `csv` file which looks like this:

```
                    open        high        low         close       volume       adjusted
2016-01-04 14:30:36 "4896,3818" "4896,4272" "4895,2363" "4895,8789" "         0" "0"     
2016-01-04 14:31:56 "4892,3579" "4894,0259" "4891,752"  "4894,0259" "         0" "0"     
2016-01-04 14:32:57 "4894,1753" "4899,2466" "4894,1753" "4898,8589" "         0" "0"     
2016-01-04 14:33:59 "4899,2227" "4899,2227" "4894,8281" "4896,5469" "         0" "0"     
2016-01-04 14:34:59 "4896,2915" "4896,418"  "4892,3838" "4893,4326" "         0" "0"     
2016-01-04 14:35:59 "4893,1196" "4896,3301" "4893,1196" "4895,4341" "         0" "0"
```

Now I want to use the package `quantmod` & `quantstrat` but the error comes up

> Error in na.omit.xts(x) : unsupported type

What I have to change?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the decimal separator in your "CSV" file is `","` instead of `"."`.  You need to specify that in whatever function you used to import the data.  For example, you would set `dec = ","` if you're using `read.csv`.

I could provide more specific help if you provided more specific details about the file format and the function you used to import it.